# Windows 7 64bit libsvm and python error: function 'svm_get_sv_indices' not foud

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7-x64, libsvm

i'm working on Windows 7 (64bit).I've installed Python 2.7.3 (32bit version) and libsvm-3.13.
When I try to launch a simple .py file that import svmutil I get an error

```
C:\libsvm-3.13\python>python provade.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "provade.py", line 1, in <module>
from svmutil import *
File "C:\libsvm-3.13\python\svmutil.py", line 3, in <module>
from svm import *
File "C:\libsvm-3.13\python\svm.py", line 288, in <module>
fillprototype(libsvm.svm_get_sv_indices, None, [POINTER(svm_model), POINTER(c_int)])
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'svm_get_sv_indices' not found
```

The provade.py is:

```
from svmutil import *
```

I've already copied libsvm.dll file into C:\windows\system32 directory...

Any suggestions? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. The libsvm-3.13 DLL is missing three functions. Try [libsvm 3.14](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) or [alternative binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libsvm).