# Libsvm in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, libsvm

I'm trying to work with LibSVM in Python but I get the following when I try using svmutil.py and svm.py downloaded with libsvm package

> undefined symbol: svm_get_sv_indices

I tried another way to install python-libsvm package in ubuntu 11.10 and it worked well.

Comment: [Apparently it's a bug.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725013/windows-7-64bit-libsvm-and-python-error-function-svm-get-sv-indices-not-foud)

Comment: Ya there was something wrong. It worked now with the second option.

Comment: I think scikit-learn also uses libsvm. It provides a very nice interface.